# how to decode <div> innerHTML to <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html

below is the `<div>` and `<textarea>` in my webpage

```
    <div id="div_1" onclick="document.getElementById("textarea_1").innerHTML=document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML;">
    paragraph 1

    paragraph 2

    paragraph 3

    paragraph 4
    </div>
<textarea id="textarea_1"></textarea>
```

when i click the div i need to show `<div>` innerHTML to `<textarea>`

but its coming like below

```
<textarea id="textarea_1">paragraph 1<br><br>paragraph 2<br><br>paragraph 3<br><br>paragraph 4</textarea>
```

i need output like this (correct format of `<div>` )

```
   <textarea id="textarea_1">
        paragraph 1

        paragraph 2

        paragraph 3

        paragraph 4
    </textarea>
```

Comment: On which browser(s) does this happen, and how did you conclude what the `textarea` element content is? Testing with the code, just with the incorrect inner double quotes (") replaced by apostrophes ('), I get no `<br>` tags on IE, Firefox, Chrome (Win 7). I think you have misunderstood what happens here (perhaps because there are line breaks in the content).

Answer (score 4):

Your `onclick` is malformed. You are delimiting it with `"` and are using `"` as the inner string delimiters as well.

You are also using a comparison operator `==` instead of an assignment operator `=`.

```
onclick="document.getElementById("textarea_1").innerHTML==document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML;"
```

This will work better:

```
onclick='document.getElementById("textarea_1").innerHTML=document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML;'
```

---

Now, to address the actual question - getting `<br>` elements when you want line breaks.

When you do:

```
document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML
```

You need to replace the `<br>` elements with line breaks:

```
document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, "\n")
```

Comment: but its coming like "paragraph 1<br><br>paragraph 2<br><br>paragraph 3<br><br>paragraph 4" format i need paragraph base

Comment: That doesn't answer his question it will not resolve the fact that he gets `<br>` tags.

Comment: For the record, it might be better to use innerText or textContent of the div, in stead of innerHTML. Then you don't have to decode. Tit shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("textarea_1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
```

This should do the trick, you have to replace `<br>` tags by real newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of innerHTML you could use value on textarea

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_1" onclick="document.getElementById("textarea_1").value = document.getElementById('div_1').innerHTML;">
        paragraph 1

        paragraph 2

        paragraph 3

        paragraph 4
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea_1"></textarea>
</body>
```

`